Rewrite python request to upload image data via api in SwiftUI
I rewrote the code as such, but it looks like it wont function the same way. and also, not sure how to rewrite the "Files" data using UIimage for a captured image.
Here is the python code i needed to rewrite:
import json
import requests

# Run inference on an image
url = "URL"
headers = {"x-api-key": "Token"}
data = {"model": "Specific model"}
with open("image.jpg", "rb") as f:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, files={"file": f})

# Check for successful response
response.raise_for_status()

# Print inference results
print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))

Here is how i tried to rewrite it
import UIKit

func uploadImage(photo: UIImage) async  {
    // Define the API endpoint and your API key
    let apiURL = URL(string: "URL")!
    let apiKey = "Token"

    guard let imageData = photo.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
        print("Could not convert image to JPEG data.")
        return
    }

    // Create the URL request
    var request = URLRequest(url: apiURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")

    // Create the JSON payload
    let base64Image = imageData.base64EncodedString()
    let jsonPayload: [String: Any] = [
        "model": "Specific model",
        "file": base64Image
    ]

    guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonPayload)  else {
        print("Could not serialize JSON data.")
        return
    }
    request.httpBody = jsonData
    
    // Perform the network request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("No data received.")
            return
        }

        // Handle the response
        do {
            if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                print("Response JSON: \(jsonResponse)")
                return
                // Parse and use the response data
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            print("JSON Error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


I have tried to use an external API and match the response and what they both send and they are both calling and sending the same data. but the swift code is not sending the same data in the same format as the python code, and also not sure how to include the "Files" part in the swift code and request protocol

There are a number of sites you can try to convert Python to Swift code,
for example
https://www.codeconvert.ai/python-to-swift-converter

coverCovert gives a good example on how to covert, but the issue I'm having is trying to push the image data from UIImage to what the API accepts, which is binary

The Python code creates, if I understand it correctly, a multipart/form-data request when both data and files is present. The URLSession does not create multipart/form-data requests. You either should consider a framework, like Alamofire, which does this for you, or consider something like contemplated here. Once you look at the amount of code required to create your own multipart/form-data request, you may really appreciate Alamofire.

looks like you maybe trying to access some AI server, OpenAI, GoogleAI etc... they usually have a Swift library to access the server, and does all the background work for you.
